# Saved emails at dashboard

Tags: forms, email, dashboard

I want to know if it's possible to send an email through a form in the website and then we can check that email in the normal email service (like gmail, etc) and the wordpress' dashboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin to create a form that will send messages to your email (like gmail, etc) and use another plugin from the same author, [Flamingo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/), to have those messages saved in WordPress database and available in the dashboard.

If you prefer to avoid plugins, here's what you need:

1. Register non-public custom post type `message` to store submissions
2. Create custom html for your form (probably with js validation)
3. Intercept form submission on `init` hook
4. Validate and secure input
5. Create new post of `message` post type with `wp_insert_post()`
6. Send email with `wp_mail()`
7. Output results below the form (validation errors or success message)

As you see, plenty of work/code. If you're a developer, you should go this way to tailor it exactly for your needs. If not, I would strongly recommend you to use mentioned plugins (or any good alternatives) to avoid having some troubles with insecure form.

Comment: First of all thank you for you answer. I was trying not to use a plugin. Is there another way?

Comment: Of course. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will see whats the best approach for this project.